# Terminal app launch and subordinate intents

Tags: linux, tasker, shell, android-emulator

I'm using Tasker to open an app at certain time and state. I wanna open the Run log menu of Tasker at the end of the app launching task.

I know that's no need to flash on screen this log but when I tried, I haven't found a way. I
can only open tasker but not launch a subordinate intent of this app.

Any help about this basic programming question will be appreciated.

Tnx in advance!

This is the description of the Tasker Manifest.xml:

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you *have root access*, you can use this command to launch the Run Log window:

```
am start -n net.dinglisch.android.tasker/.RunLog
```

*RunLog* activity, *without root access* however, fails to launch and throws the error:

```
Permission Denial: startActivity asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
```

Perhaps the [following attribute](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exported), as mentioned in the manifest, is the cause of the issue.

```
android:exported="false"
```

Comment: Hi Firelord! Tnx. I tried lot of commands. First using always --user 0 permission to access all users. The RunLog intent doesn't have the dot in its name so I didn't get the result of open it. I'll try your solution. Tnx again

Comment: Unknown command

Comment: If you're using a terminal app, then the correct command is: `su -c 'am start -n net.dinglisch.android.tasker/.RunLog'` (note that root access is needed). If you're using Tasker and want to run this command from inside it for automation, then try Run Shell -> Command: `am start -n net.dinglisch.android.tasker/.RunLog`, check Root.

Comment: I solved the problem. The package is the name of the activity. In this case .taskerm instead of .tasker